# How to create local branch from remote branch not checkouting this branch?

Tags: git

Let's say I have remote branch `origin/foo`. I want to create local branch `foo` pointing the same commit remote branch `origin/foo` is pointing now. I can do `git checkout foo` and this is what I need except it will change by working directory and `HEAD`. Is there any way to achieve the same result without checkouting `foo` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can do `git branch foo origin/foo`.

Then you'll end up with local branch `foo` and it will be tracking remote `origin/foo`.